# rsync and xfr#1, to-chk=0/1, what do they mean?

Tags: debian, rsync

I do stuff such as :-

```
$ copy debian-8.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso /media/shirish/4719-38E5/
```

Copy here is an alias for :-

```
$ alias copy
alias copy='rsync --progress -ravz'
```

When it does the command it takes a long time to complete and does :-

```
$ copy debian-8.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso /media/shirish/4719-38E5/
sending incremental file list
debian-8.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
  3,607,855,104 100%    9.11MB/s    0:06:17 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

sent 3,466,268,276 bytes  received 35 bytes  3,481,937.03 bytes/sec
total size is 3,607,855,104  speedup is 1.04
```

Now I have two questions :-

a. -z in rsync is not documented, does anybody know what does it do ? It is very much possible that the flag was there before and is no longer there.

Another thing, does anybody know what `xfr#1, to-chk=0/1` actually do ?

I usually perform `sync` after the command is finished, does anybody know if it's ok to use it or not as copying takes a long time.

Also can people some nicer, better ways so I could use an alias to accomplish the same. For me having progress is important. Few months ago, I did come across an advanced `cp` which also has a progress bar for showing the progress of a file being copied.

Hopeful of a quick resolution of the above.

Comment: It's better to ask specific, individual questions so that people can give specific individual answers. Your main question is about rsync, but you piled in questions about sync and ideas for a better alias.

Comment: Please either post your answer (the "it got solved" part) as an answer (yes, that's allowed) or close your question—it doesn't seem like you have an unanswered question anymore.

Comment: @JeffSchaller you are right, but the answer got answered by our friend don_crissti. Now just need to close it, but doesn't seem a way to close it :(

Comment: I don't want to delete it, let it remain here. I actually saw another question where the user asked the same question. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215271/understanding-the-output-of-info-progress2-from-rsync which is similar to mine. So can direct him here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It got solved -

> ```
> -z, --compress              compress file data during the transfer
>     --compress-level=NUM    explicitly set compression level
> ```
>
> this part seems to be the interesting one.
>
> ```
>     --progress
> ```
>
> This option tells rsync to print information showing the progress of the transfer. This gives a bored user something to watch.
>   With a modern rsync this is the same as specifying
>
> ```
>     --info=flist2,name,progress
> ```
>
> but any user-supplied settings for those info flags takes precedence (e.g. "`--info=flist0 --progress`").
>
> While rsync is transferring a regular file, it updates a progress line that looks like this:
>
> ```
> 782448  63%  110.64kB/s    0:00:04
> ```
>
> In  this example, the receiver has reconstructed 782448 bytes or 63% of the sender’s file, which is being reconstructed at a
>   rate of 110.64 kilobytes per second, and the transfer will finish in 4 seconds if the current rate is maintained until the end.
>
> These statistics can be misleading if rsync’s delta-transfer algorithm is in use. For example, if the sender’s file
>   consists of the basis file followed  by additional data, the reported
>   rate will probably drop dramatically when the receiver gets to the
>   literal data, and the transfer will probably take much longer to
>   finish than the receiver estimated as it was finishing the matched
>   part of the file.
>
> When the file transfer finishes, rsync replaces the progress line with a summary line that looks like this:
>
> ```
> 1,238,099 100%  146.38kB/s    0:00:08  (xfr#5, to-chk=169/396)
> ```
>
> In  this  example, the file was 1,238,099 bytes long in total, the average rate of transfer for the whole file was
>   146.38 kilobytes per second over the 8 seconds that it took to complete, **it was the 5th transfer of a regular file during the current**
>   **rsync session, and  there are 169 more files for the receiver to check**
>   **(to see if they are up-to-date or not) remaining out of the 396 total**
>   **files in the file-list.**
>
> In an incremental recursion scan, rsync won’t know the total number of files in the file-list until it reaches the
>   ends of the scan, but since it starts to transfer files during the
>   scan, it will display a line with the text "ir-chk" (for incremental
>   recursion check) instead of "to-chk" until the point that it knows the
>   full size of the list, at which point it will switch to using
>   "to-chk". Thus,  seeing  "ir-chk"  lets  you  know that the total
>   count of files in the file list is still going to increase (and each
>   time it does, the count of files left to check  will increase by the
>   number of the files added to the list).