# progress bar while copying a file from hdd to usb drive (no rsync)

Tags: debian, rsync, cp

I used to [rsync and xfr#1, to-chk=0/1, what do they mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231647/rsync-and-xfr1-to-chk-0-1-what-do-they-mean) but with the recent rsync bug https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=862899 I don't know the solution.

Does anybody of any alternative which could provide the same features as rsync did for this specific purpose ?

Answer (score 2):

If you’re specifically looking for “copy with progress information”, check out `pv`

```
pv source > target
```

or `progress`

```
cp source target & progress -mp $!
```

Neither of these will account for the `sync` time to a USB drive, but `rsync` wouldn’t either AFAIK.